# TypeScript: Read generic type of value in object

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have this interface:

```
interface Api {
  state: Converter<State>;
  water: Converter<Water>;
  version: Converter<Versions>;
}
```

and I have a function called `write`

```
write(name, value);
```

now what I want to achieve is that the type of `value` should be the generic of Converter depending on the first parameter (`name`).

So if I call `write("state", value)` -> `value` should be `State`. The same goes for `"water"` and `"version"`.

```
write("state, value);    // value should be type of State
write("water", value);   // value should be type of Water
write("version", value); // value should be type of Versions
```

I implemented the first parameter like so:

```
write(name: keyof Api, value: ???)
```

I found that I can get the corresponding value to `keyof Api` like so:

```
write<K extends keyof Api>(name: K, value: Api[K])
```

but that gives me `Converter<State>` for `"state"`. Is there a way I can access the generic in `Converter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this helps, since I'm not sure what your `Converter` interface looks like.

But with this:

```
interface Converter<T> {
  converter: T;
}
```

And these interfaces for `State`, `Water` and `Version`:

```
interface State {
  state: string;
}

interface Water {
  water: string;
}

interface Version {
  version: string;
}
```

You can do this:

```
function write<K extends keyof Api>(name: K, value: Api[K]["converter"]) {}
```

```
write("state", { state: "x" }); // Works

write("water", { state: "x" }); // Argument of type '{ state: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Water'.

write("water", { water: "x" }); // Works
```

But it adds a property to your `Converter` interface.

Comment: hey thanks! that is what I am doing now! but I had to make the `converter` property optional or I would have to actually set that field with every usage of the interface. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

if you have acces to Converter iterface/type or whatever just extend it with this type

or create extended interface like this

```
interface Converter<T> {
  p1: any;
  p2: any;
}
interface IExtendedConverter<T> extends Converter<T> {
  type: T;
}

interface IApi {
  state: IExtendedConverter<string>;
  water: IExtendedConverter<number>;
}

const write = <K extends keyof IApi>(name: K, value: IApi[K]['type']) => {
  return;
};

const str = write('state', '1'); // here value has to be string
const num = write('water', 1); // here value has to be number
```

EDIT based on question

one solution would be define this parameter

```
const extendedConverterState: IExtendedConverter<string> = {
  ...converter,
  type: '',
};

const extendedConverterNumber: IExtendedConverter<number> = {
  ...converter,
  type: 1,
};

const api: IApi = {
  state: extendedConverterState,
  water: extendedConverterNumber,
};
```

this is somehow retarded solution since you would just create this property whitch will never be used.

other solution can be to create type parameter as optionla

```
interface IExtendedConverter<T> extends Converter<T> {
  type?: T;
}
```

but this souliton will ceate your parameter in write function as optional (possible undefined)

well maybe ther is better solution to acces this generic type. idk

Comment: Hey thank you so much! That works perfectly. I have a problem though: From the outside the type checking works exactly as intended, but when I create an API object (`const api: Api = { state, water, version };`) TS tells me that `Property 'type' is missing ` in `state`, `water` and `version`. Currently those variables are of the type `Converter`, if I change the type to `IExtendedConverter ` it tells me `Property 'type' is missing in type ` but I don't know how to define it

Comment: Hey, I added `type?: T;` to `Converter` and got rid of `IExtendedConverter ` and kept the rest as you suggested. This works perfectly for me. Thank you!